# Linq To Sql, Extended Delete of an Entity wont let it delete anymore

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, dbml

I have 2 entities, for example Parent and Child.

what I'm trying to achieve here is to have Delete method of entity Child extended so i can do some stuff when it is Deleting, here is what i have done so far:

```
partial class MyDataClassDataContext
{
    partial void DeleteChild(Child instance)
    {
        //My Custom Code Here
    }
}
```

there is an event in the code that would delete a Parent and all of its Children, something like this:

```
 void DeleteParent(Parent itemParent)
 {
    var ListChilds = db.Parents.Where(p=>p == itemParent).Select(p=>p.Childs);
    if(ListCilds.Any())
    {
       db.Chields.DeleteAllOnSubmit(ListCilds);
    }
    db.Parents.DeleteOnSubmit(itemParent);
    db.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

This code always worked, but when i try to extend the Delete method of Child, it seems to wait for me to decide whether or not to delete them, and i get an exception that Parent cannot be deleted where it have Child.

Comment: What do you mean by extending the Delete method, are you trying to change the definition of an auto generated class

Comment: i dont want to change its original definition, i just want to add an event like method to it so, when it's deleted i do something.

Comment: i know it's possible with Triggers in SQL, but is it possible with linq-to-sql ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to find all the Parents in your delete child method and remove this specific child form theirs Childs collection...this will remove the relation and then you can delete the child itself.